# Damage or Heal based on the buttons you press

Tags: swift, ios, cocoa

If you press the damage button, it will damage armor before health. If you press the heal button, it will heal armor before health.

The project is here: [https://github.com/austingaee/DamageHealth-Armor](https://github.com/austingaee/DamageHealth-Armor/tree/bda2764f5051d688a2cbf75a3328e6abe979f707)

Are there any improvements I can make?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var armorBarView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var healthBarView: UIView!

    var damageAmount : Float = 0.0
    var healAmount : Float = 0.0

    //Maximum Health
    var barAmount : Float = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        damageAmount = Float(self.armorBarView.frame.size.width) * 0.10
        healAmount = Float(self.armorBarView.frame.size.width) * 0.05
        barAmount = Float(self.armorBarView.frame.size.width)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func damageBar(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //7.63 came from how much damage was left after 10 hits
        if self.armorBarView.frame.size.width > 7.63 {
            self.armorBarView.frame.size.width -= CGFloat(damageAmount)
        } else if self.healthBarView.frame.size.width > 7.63 {
            self.healthBarView.frame.size.width -= CGFloat(damageAmount)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func healBar(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.armorBarView.frame.size.width < CGFloat(barAmount) {
            self.armorBarView.frame.size.width += CGFloat(healAmount)
            print(self.armorBarView.frame.size.width)
        } else if self.healthBarView.frame.size.width < CGFloat(barAmount) {
            self.healthBarView.frame.size.width += CGFloat(healAmount)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it okay to post a link to my github?

Comment: Yes it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

not so much but some tiny changes:

**DRY**

i just would avoid all the `self.healthBarView.frame.size.width`

and make methods:

- `getWidth`
- `setWidth`(or `updateWidth` because you set the diff)

**Constants**

the magic numbers like `0.1` `0.05` `10` i would define as constants so it can changed only at one place. 7.63 i would calculate

**Naming**

rename `barAmount` to `maxAmount`

create `minAmount`

**Float/CGFloat**

the Float / CGFloat is realy needed? just put them also into getWidth and updateWidth

**else if**

the else if block is not needed (same condition)

**7.63**

this is an value depending on your setup - it should also calculated so it not changes when you init it with different width

**Resulting Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var armorBarView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var healthBarView: UIView!

    var damageAmount : Float = 0.0
    var healAmount : Float = 0.0

    // Min/Maximum Health
    var minAmount: Float = 0.00
    var maxAmount : Float = 0.0

    // how much damage was left after this number of hits
    let minAmountHits:Float = 10

    let demageFactor: Float = 0.10
    let healFactor: Float = 0.05

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initAmount()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func initAmount(){
        damageAmount = getWidth() * demageFactor
        healAmount = getWidth() * healFactor
        maxAmount = getWidth()
        minAmount = maxAmount - minAmountHits * damageAmount
    }

    @IBAction func damageBar(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if getWidth() > minAmount {
            updateWidth(-damageAmount)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func healBar(_ sender: Any) {
        if getWidth() < maxAmount {
            updateWidth(healAmount)
        }
    }

    func getWidth() -> Float {
        return Float(self.armorBarView.frame.size.width)
    }

    func updateWidth(_ amount: Float) {
        self.healthBarView.frame.size.width += CGFloat(amount)
        print(self.armorBarView.frame.size.width)
    }
}
```